# Why are my tomato plant leaves turning brown, shriveling, dying?

Tags: diagnosis, vegetables, tomatoes

This has been progressive over the last 6 weeks, leaves turning dry, brown and getting very thin and shriveling like paper on a Tomato "Blue Berries" cherry tomato plant.

The closest I could guess was it was a fungus/disease of some sort after reading this article:
https://dengarden.com/gardening/Yellow-leaves-on-tomato-plants-Get-rid-of-yellow-tomato-leaves

> Tomato plant leaves do not begin by turning brown unless it's a fungal
>   attack such as Septoria leaf spot or other fungal infections...

I bought a fungicide and have applied it once 10 days ago but as you can see still deteriorating, we've had 3 days of rain and I'm due to spray it again; am I on the right track? I'm really quite puzzled.

The plant receives a fortnightly dose of diluted Kelp Fertiliser and Liquid Potash.

It is now Spring here in Australia. If you need any more pics let me know.
Thank you!

**The plant used to be in excellent health back in August:**
[image]

**This evening:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**And these shots from October 1:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks fellow gardeners

Comment: I have the same sad issue... I only water when the soil isn't damped after testing with a finger, and they grow in 100% compost. They started really well.. so sad.